# Twilio - how to play music in between gather completion and gather action completion - waiting for a heavy API to run?

Tags: php, api, twilio

I am trying to grab the user's voice input, send to an API, and speak the APIs response -- essentially this on loop until the user hangs up. Unfortunately, it's a heavy API, so it takes 4-6 seconds to respond, leading to a lot of silence on the end of the user. I would like to play an MP3 file during these silences (after `<Gather>` finishes listening, until the API response is ready.

I have `twilio.php`

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/xml'); 
$bytes = random_bytes(15);
$threadId = bin2hex($bytes);
?>
<Response>
    <Gather input="speech" action="/process.php?tid=<?php echo $threadId; ?>" method="POST">
        <Say>How can I help you today?</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Then I have `process.php`

```
<?php

$userInput = $_POST['SpeechResult'];


$ch = curl_init('https://internalapi.com/endpoint');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userInput));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $api_key,
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response_data = json_decode($response, true);
$responseFinal = $response_data['message']['content'];



header('Content-Type: application/xml');
echo '<Response><Gather input="speech" action="/process.php?tid='.$tid.'" method="POST"><Say>' . $responseFinal . '</Say></Gather></Response>';
```

The response from the internal API can take 4-6 seconds, leading to a lot of silence on the user's side. I want to add 2 seconds of timeout to gather, and then play an mp3 file until the API response is received. This is relatively tricky to do in PHP.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could deal with this in an asynchronous fashion and return a TwiML that only plays the MP3 when the API call is triggered.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play loop="10">https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

In parallel, you would save the call ID and trigger your long-running operation. Once the operation is done, you'd [modify the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress/php) with the new TwiMl with the next `<Gather>`.

```php
<?php

// Update the path below to your autoload.php,
// see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
$sid = getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
$token = getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$call = $twilio->calls("CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
               ->update([
                            "twiml" => "<Response><Gather>...</Gather></Response>"
                        ]
               );

print($call->to);
```

Comment: Feel free to confirm this question with the green checkmark button if you found it useful.